# Why won't some jQuery code(s) work when isolated in unique <script> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is not code specific. It is a very general question, prompted by something I've been observing while building this website, and it really puzzles me.

In the head section of the site I'm working on, I have all the jQuery codes that run the site, enclosed within  document ready methods, which are in turn enclosed within  tags in the head section of the site.  I usually put each code that performs a unique function, within unique script tags.  But I began to notice that some of my jQ codes wouldn't work at all when isolated in their own unique document ready method.  Then when I transposed this same code to a neighboring document ready method containing another unrealated code which already works, the said code works fine.

So the puzzle is, why wouldn't these codes work when isolated?  Are there certain circumstances when this might be the case? Perhaps there is something fundamental about jQuery/javascript that i don't understand that's going on here.  Has this been anyones's experience?  Answers appreciated.

---

well here is one of the scripts that wont work on its own (when isolated). It loops through all the  elementss within an  checking if the href attribute matches the url. If it does, it adds a class to the

parent of that  element. The purpose is to highlight the appropriate menu item of the page being displayed.

```
            <script type = "text/javascript">


                $(document).ready(function() {


                                   //Menu highlights.

                    var curURL =  document.location.toString();

                    $('.topnav1  li.highlight').removeClass('highlight'); 



                    $('.topnav1 li a').each(

                         function(){

                                if  (curURL.indexOf(this.href) != -1){

                                   $(this).closest('li').addClass('highlight');

                            } 

                             }  

                    );  





                });







            </script>
```

Well standing on its own, this script doesn't work, but once I include it within the document ready method of another unrelated script, it works. Here's what I mean.

```
            <script type = "text/javascript">
    //To load ajax pages. And menu highlights.



                $(document).ready(function() {


                                   //Menu highlights.

                    var curURL =  document.location.toString();

                    $('.topnav1  li.highlight').removeClass('highlight'); 



                    $('.topnav1 li a').each(

                         function(){

                                if  (curURL.indexOf(this.href) != -1){

                                 $(this).closest('li').addClass('highlight');

                                } 

                             }  

                    );  








                            //Load pages via Ajax

                    // Check for hash value in URL


                    var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);


                    var href = $('.topnav li  a').each(function(){


                 var href = $(this).attr('href');


                         if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-5)){


                        var toLoad = hash+'.html  .wrapper_inner';


                        $('.wrapper_inner').load(toLoad)


                        }


                    });





                $('.topnav li a').click(function(){





                    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' .wrapper_inner';


                $('.wrapper_inner').slideUp('fast',loadContent);


                        $('#load').remove();


                        $('#tier3').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');


                        $('#load').fadeIn('normal');


                        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);


                        function loadContent() {


                    $('.wrapper_inner').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())


                        }


                        function showNewContent() {


                    $('.wrapper_inner').slideDown('slow',hideLoader());


                        }


                        function hideLoader() {


                    $('#load').fadeOut('normal');


                        }


                        return false;





                    });


            });//End of ducument ready method











            </script>
```

This I may add is just one example. I have two other scripts that didn't work on their own but worked once I boxed them in with the above script.

Comment: Post some sample code to clear ambiguities.

Comment: There is no general reason why such a problem would occur which means it has to do with your specific code and what you're trying to do.  So, we'd have to see some specific code that has this problem to offer ideas.

Comment: Likely you have either HTML or javascript syntax error that prevents execution of the code below it. Inspect the DOM to make sure all your script tags are there. Check the console to see if there are any errors.

Answer (score 1):

One possible circumstance is if the `<script>` elements with the `$(document).ready(function{})` code comes before the `<script>` element containing the jQuery library. Here are a couple of examples:

**Good:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("You will see this.");
    });
</script>
```

**Bad:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("You will not see this.");
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

I know it seems simple, but in response to your question, this is one situation that will prevent execution.

Comment: Well that's not what happened in my case.  I actually connect the the jQ librabry before putting any other code into my header section.  Perhaps an example would much better illustrate what Im talking about.